# Kinematics confusion regarding sign of integration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, velocity, calculus

I was solving some problems regarding non-inertial frames, and Newtonian mechanics in general, when I faced a major doubt regarding one of the seemingly simple topics, and I'd appreciate it if someone clear this doubt for me.

Suppose, I have a body that I drop from a certain height under gravity. I want to know the velocity of the body at a certain height from the ground. There are no forces acting on the body, apart from gravity.

$$m\frac{dv}{dt} = mv\frac{dv}{dx}= -mg $$

As you can see, I have taken the vertically up direction as positive, and thus $g$ is negative. Then it is just simple integration :

$$\int_0^vvdv=-g\int_{x_i}^{x_f}dx$$

Since $x_f<x_i,$ we get the expected answer, as the integral should be positive on both sides. This is perfectly fine.

However, let me now consider the downward direction, as positive. In that case, $g$ would be positive. Hence, the only change that we'll get would be :

$$\int_0^vvdv=g\int_{x_i}^{x_f}dx$$

However, since $x_f<x_i,$ the right-hand side becomes negative, while the left-hand side can only be positive. This is clearly impossible, so there must be some negative sign on the RHS to balance this. I would have to flip the limits of the integral to make sense of this. I'm not being able to understand where this extra negative sign would come from if I take the downward direction as positive.

My guess is, in this case, $dx$ would be negative. However, I don't seem to know why? Can $dx$ carry a negative sign? If not, how do we resolve this issue?

If I take the downward direction to be positive, and so $g$ is positive, how do I show that velocity increases or find the velocity at some height above the ground?

In simple problems like this one, this doesn't create that much confusion. But if we include more force terms, that depend on height, and then integrate, our choice of positive up or down seems to matter a lot.

For some reason, $dx$ and $g$ seem to have opposite signs in front of them. I can't seem to figure out why. I'm really sorry in advance if this problem is rather trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second part, your assumption that $x_f\lt x_i$ is incorrect. In fact, $x_f\gt x_i$ if you take the down direction to be positive. See the analysis below for a more detailed answer.

---

**In the first part with down being the negative direction:**

Your first equation $$mv\frac{dv}{dx}= -mg$$ would yield $$\int vdv=-g\int_{x_i}^{x_f}dx$$ so that there is no $m$ symbol (you have accidentally left the $m$ in your equations). This will yield the equation $$v^2=-2g(x_f - x_i)$$ so that for $v\gt 0$ then $x_f\lt x_i$

In other words, $x_f$ must be more negative (meaning smaller) than $x_i$ for $v$ to be positive since we are taking the down direction to be negative. If for example we take some point where $x=0$, then after a certain time $x_i=-5$ then a little later $x_f=-20$. This means that $x_f-x_i\lt 0$ which is consistent.

**In the second part with down being the positive direction:**

Now you are taking downward to be positive in which case for $$v^2=2g(x_f - x_i)$$ then $x_f \gt x_i$ so that $$v^2\gt 0$$ always meaning $v\gt 0$

Your assumption that $x_f\lt x_i$ is incorrect. If for example we take $x_i=5$ then the final value for $x$ can be $x_f=20$ since the positive direction is down so that $x_f-x_i$ is positive.

Comment: Suppose I consider the ground to be the reference point. An object has been dropped from a height of $10$m, and I want to find out its velocity at $5$m height. Here $h_f-h_i <0$. However, gravity is also negative, so we have an increment in velocity. However, say I have the same reference point on the ground, but my positive direction is now downward. So $g$ is positive. I want to know what would be the precise limits of my integration. My feeling is, it would just be from $-h_i$ to $-h_f$, as both these heights are above the reference i.e. in the negative direction. Is that correct ?

Comment: If I make this change, $h_f-h_i$ becomes positive, and thus the entire thing makes sense again. I've not changed my reference level, just the direction of positive and negative. I was just asking, how exactly would the limits of my integral change.

Comment: Yes, you were correct the first time, if you take down to be the negative direction.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense if you are always consistent with direction of displacements and the sign of the acceleration $g$.

Comment: You mean that, when the positive direction is up, and reference level is set at $0$, then the ball falls from $10$m height to $5$m height. But, if the reference is still $0$, but positive direction is downward, the ball falls from $-10$m to $-5$m instead. Is that correct ?

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, since your positive x axis points down, $x_f$ would be greater than $x_i$, no?

Comment: Suppose, the initial height of a ball is $10$m and I want to find it's velocity at say $5$m. Assuming positive $x$ axis upward, it is obvious that initial height is more than final height. However, I want to know who would these limits change, if the positive $x$ axis were downward. Like would we have negative signs in front of them, and if so, then why ?

Comment: If acceleration is positive downward that means the x axis is increasing downward,  e.g. you are measuring position in "meters below the top of Mt. Everest" instead of "meters above sea level"